# Why am I getting an empty string when i updating using mongoose?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm trying to update specific information and leave other information. But what is happening right now is I should still type the other information or else it will be an empty. This is what I received after sending the information:

```
"studentId": "",
```

so in this example, the admin has the ability to change the studentId information, but right now all I want to change is the status. **(vice-versa)**

This is my front end. I'm storing it to state,

```
  const [data,setData] = useState({
    studentId: '',
    status: ''
  })

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault() 
    try {
       await userRequest.put(`/users/${userId}`,data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log({error: error.message})
    }
  }

<div className="formInput">
    <label>Student ID</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder={userInfo.studentId}  onChange={(e) => 
         setData({...data, studentId: e.target.value})} />
 </div>

<div className="formInput">
   <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 200 }}>
     <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Status</InputLabel>
       <Select
         labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
         id="demo-simple-select-helper"
         defaultValue={userInfo.status}
         label="Status"
          onChange={(e) => setData({...data, status: e.target.value})}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
              </MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value="pending">Pending</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value="active">Active</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value="disable">Disable</MenuItem>
                     </Select>
                </FormControl>

                </div>
```

Backend.js

```
router.put('/:id',  async (req,res) =>{
    if(req.body.password){
        req.body.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            req.body.password, 
            process.env.PASSWORD_SEC)
            .toString();
    }

    try {
        const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            $set: req.body
        }, {new: true})
        res.status(200).json(updatedUser)
        console.log(updatedUser)
    } catch (error) {
       res.status(500).json({message:error.message})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is a good approach but I change this

```
  const [data,setData] = useState({})
```

and make handle change like this

```
onChange={(e) => setData({...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})}
```